# Javascript Array - getting random photo to display when browser loads

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

[Free Code Camp Project](https://codepen.io/mbert86/pen/QJjExy)

I am working on a tribute page project, and have decided to add a javascript random photo array to the project. This is working fine, but I cant figure out how to get a random photo to appear whenever the browser reloads.

here is my html

```
<div id="albumCovers"></div>
<button id='randomBut'>View Random Album Covers</button>
<div><img id='movieImg'></div>
```

here is the javascript

```
var randomizer = document.getElementById("randomBut");
var randImg = document.getElementById("movieImg");

var movieImages = [
    "all.jpg", 
    "dontgrowup.jpg",
    "everythingSux.jpg",
    "enjoy.jpg",
    "college.jpg",
    "hyper.jpg",
    "cooltobeyou.jpg"
];

randomizer.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieImages.length) + 0;
    randImg.src = movieImages[randNum];
    randomizer.click();
});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This should help -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by a user in the comments, you want to utilize [`DOMContentLoaded`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. You can see in the code below I created an `init` function that gets called upon `DOMContentLoaded` being fired. The `init` function's job is to:

1) Make an initial call to the `setRandomImage` function

2) Set `setRandomImage` as the `click` event handler on `randomizer`

```js
var randomizer = document.getElementById("randomBut");
var randImg = document.getElementById("movieImg");
var movieImages = [
  "all.jpg",
  "dontgrowup.jpg",
  "everythingSux.jpg",
  "enjoy.jpg",
  "college.jpg",
  "hyper.jpg",
  "cooltobeyou.jpg"
];


//When the HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  //Make an inital function call ("when the browser loads")
  setRandomImage();

  //Attach a click event listener to the random button
  randomizer.addEventListener("click", setRandomImage);
}


//Put this code in a function since we want to call it multiple times
function setRandomImage() {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieImages.length) + 0;
  randImg.src = movieImages[randNum];

  //randomizer.click(); -- I dont understand the point of this line of code, so I commented.

  console.log(`Displaying ${randImg.src}`)
}
```

```html
<div id="albumCovers"></div>
<button id='randomBut'>View Random Album Covers</button>
<div><img id='movieImg'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your random code into a function and call that function on load and button press as shown below. Run the snippet more then once to see the random image generated. Below is a working example.

```js
var randomizer = document.getElementById("randomBut");
  var randImg = document.getElementById("movieImg");
  var movieImages = ["https://image.ibb.co/caPP3V/all.jpg", 
  "https://image.ibb.co/btn2OV/dontgrowup.jpg",
   "https://image.ibb.co/kQoHOV/everything-Sux.jpg",
   "https://image.ibb.co/c2UP3V/enjoy.jpg",
   "https://image.ibb.co/ifbFAA/college.jpg",
   "https://image.ibb.co/fe7Yxq/hyper.jpg",
   "https://image.ibb.co/dKtj3V/cooltobeyou.jpg"];

 
 randomizer.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rans();
  });

function rans(){
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieImages.length) + 0  
    
    randImg.src = movieImages[randNum] ;
}
```

```css
#main {
 margin: 0;
}

#headline {
 background: black;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

/* The code below makes the main image able to shrink properly for phones, and place the image in its own line. "height: auto;" keeps the original aspect ratio of image */
#logo {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: roboto;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#history{
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: roboto;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#content {
 background: white;
 margin: auto;
}

#milo {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 200px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;

}

#img-div {
 background: black;
 margin: auto;
}

#img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#img-caption {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: roboto;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#albumCovers {
 padding-top: 35px;
}

#randomBut {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#movieImg {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#wiki {
 text-align: center;
  padding-top: 35px;
 padding-bottom: 35px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: roboto;
 font-weight: 18px;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>The Descendents Tribute Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins|Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="main" onload="rans()">

<div id="main">

<div id="headline">

 <img id="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/fDZPnq/descendents.jpg" alt="descendents" border="0">

 <h1 id="title">A tribute to one of the most influential bands in Punk Rock</h1>
</div>

 <div class="content">
  <img id="milo" src="https://image.ibb.co/dmcNqA/milo.jpg">

  <h1 id="history">HISTORY</h1>
  <ul id="tribute-info">
   <li>1977 - The Descendents was started by original guitarist Frank Naventta</li>
   <li>1978 - Bill Stevenson would join the band as drummer and became one of the main songwriters. Tony Lombardo joined as bassist.</li>
   <li>The band's music at the time was described by Stevenson as a "coffee'd-out blend of rock-surf-pop-punk music".</li>
   <li>1979 - The band enlisted Milo Aukerman as their vocalist, who would go on to become the iconic face of the band.</li>
   <li>1981 - Fat ep was released</li>
   <li>1982 - "Milo Goes To College" was released, and is considered one of the most influential albums in punk rock.</li>
   <li>The band went on hiatus from 1983-1985 while Milo was in college. Bill Stevenson had joined Black Flag in this time. Frank Navetta Burned all his equipment and never returned to the band.</li>
   <li>1985 - The band reformed and released the album "I Don't Want to Grow Up"</li>
   <li>1986 - "Enjoy" was released. Karl Alvarez joined as bassist, and Stephen Egerton joined as guitarist.</li>
   <li>1987 - "All" was released. Milo left the band after touring for the album had finished. The remaining members carried on under the name "All"   </li>
   <li>1996 - The band had reformed with Aukerman, and released the album "Everything Sux" on Epitaph Records</li>
   <li>1997 - Aukerman left again to pursue his chemistry career</li>
   <li>2002-2004 - The band began working on a new album in the early 2000s, with Aukerman doing vocal work from a different studio in Delaware.</li>
   <li>2004 - "Cool to be you" was released on Fat Wreck Chords.</li>
   <li>2008 - Original guitarist Frank Navetta passed away.</li>
   <li>2010 - The band reunited again to play occasional one-off shows, but it was never considered a full reunion.</li>
   <li>2013 - "Filmage" was released, which was a documentary about Descendents and All.</li>
   <li>2016-present - "Hypercaffium Spazzinate" was released. Aukerman had left his career as a chemist, and the band has since returned to touring full time.</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="img-div">
  <img id="img" src="https://image.ibb.co/iy08DV/band-Photo.png" alt="band-Photo" border="0">
  <div id="img-caption">From left to right: Karl Alvarez (bass), Bill Stevenson (drums), Stephen Egerton (guitar), Milo Aukerman (vocals)
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="albumCovers"></div>
 <button id='randomBut'>View Random Album Covers</button>
 <div><img id='movieImg'></div>
 </div>


 <div id="wiki">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descendents" target="_blank">Descendents Wikipedia</a>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tribute.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

by adding moving the code used in the `onclick` binding for the button into its own function `rans()`, having the click event of the button call the function and then adding `onload="rans()"` to the body tag  you get the same functionality and get a random image on page load.

Key code changes:
Change this:

```
randomizer.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieImages.length) + 0;
    randImg.src = movieImages[randNum];
    randomizer.click();
});
```

to this:

```
randomizer.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rans();
  });

function rans(){
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieImages.length) + 0  

    randImg.src = movieImages[randNum] ;
}
```

and add onload to the body tag:

```
<body id="main" onload="rans()">
```

Answer (score 0):

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', theSameHandlerAsForClick);

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
randImg.src = movieImages[randNum] ;
```

by this one

```
randImg.setAttribute('src', movieImages[randNum]) ;
```

Comment: I just tried that but it didnt do anything

randomizer.addEventListener("click", function() 
{
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
movieImages.length) + 0  

randImg.setAttribute('src', movieImages[randNum]) ;
randomizer.click();